# Is it possible to set the parent form of an external application before starting the process?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, exe

I have a winforms application (.net 5.0) that comprises two forms - one for the operator (to setup different options/enter data, admin duties) and another for the user to interact with (play games, follow instructions etc). Each form is displayed on separate monitors, with both visible/available when the application is run.

One requirement of the application is to run external applications (games) in the user form. The user form contains a panel (as a header) and several custom user controls. One of the user controls becomes the parent of the external application.

Using the code below I am able to run external applications inside the user form. However, the applications all start outside of the form (as indicated by the appearance of a 'splash' screen) before being moved inside the user form using `SetParent(...)`.

What I want to achieve is for the 'splash' screen not to appear before moving the external application to the user control. I understand that causes/solutions may range depending on the application in question, so guidance is welcomed in lieu of a solution.

Much of the code below has been sourced from SO and Google more widely, however I have been unable to find references to 'splash' screen issues.

```
public static int GWL_STYLE = -16;
public static int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000; //window with border
public static int WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000; //window with double border but no title
public static int WS_CAPTION = WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME; //window with a title bar
public const uint WS_SIZEBOX = 0x00040000;

...

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr Handle, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool repaint);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

public static void HideWindowBorders(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    var style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE); //gets current style
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, (uint)(style & ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_SIZEBOX))); //removes caption and the sizebox from current style
}

...

// Button click in the operator form starts the external application
private void playSuperTuxBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Process superTux = new Process();

   superTux.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\SuperTux\bin\supertux2.exe"; // 0.6.3
   superTux.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   superTux.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
   superTux.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

   superTux.Start();

   superTux.WaitForInputIdle();

   while (superTux.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
   {
       Thread.Sleep(100);
       superTux.Refresh();
   }

   RemoveMenuBar(superTux.MainWindowHandle);
   HideWindowBorders(superTux.MainWindowHandle);
   SetParent(superTux.MainWindowHandle, RebotControlForm.uiForm.conUIGamePlay.Handle);
   MoveWindow(superTux.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, RebotControlForm.uiForm.conUIGamePlay.Width, RebotControlForm.uiForm.conUIGamePlay.Height, true);
}
```

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683): "Yes ... It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws... they become near-impossible to manage if one or both of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in a cross-process window tree. (I often see this question in the context of somebody who wants to grab a window belonging to another process and forcibly graft it into their own process."

Answer (score 0):

`MainWindowHandle` is not an actual thing in Windows, it is faked by .NET.

To catch all windows you would have to use a hook of some kind, `SetWinEventHook` or a CBT hook.